# Linking quotation and order data in way that lets order data to be flexible

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, datamodel

I have developed a data model as per screenshot. The purpose of this is to have all the relevant quotation data "mapped" out for further analysis.

The data between orders/quotations/invoices etc is linked by generating link tables, which comes out directly from SAP document flow (the document flow table only holds main document number, like quotation number and a line number of the material).

The links serve their purpose and are correct, if the quotations weren't so "flexible".
Orders to invoices are linked on a material level, so there cannot be any difference between them.
But Quotations are not hard linked to orders, I'll explain below.

For example if a quotation is created for 2 lines, which then later is converted in to an order, the user is not forced to keep the order in the same structure as the quotation, he/she can add more items in the order/change quantities etc. so they can really only be linked on the header level, aka Document number to document number.
So this is where I need some help.

I have tried to link the quotations to order in 2 ways, but they both have their issues.

1. Doc to Doc. - The lines are duplicated when trying to create a report at an item level.
2. Doc + line number to Doc + line number - If the order has extra lines added on to compared to quotation, this data is not captured in the flow.

I am hoping someone had a similar task/issue in the past and would be kind enough to share their experience/approach.

Regards

[image: Data model]